# Looping through dataset and storing data in array in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, dataset

I am trying to load all the groups into an `Array` then loop through those groups and see how many assets they have per agent, if assets are more than agents than move them to our dummy group 0. but i am new to this `DataSet` and `TableAdapator`.

basically 
Group--agent--assets

```
0--0--10
1--3--3
2--3--5
3--10--15
```

so group 2 has 2 extra assets i want to move them to our empty group 0

Please guide

```
Dim rs, lines
rs = cn.Execute("select grp from tskmsgrp where listid = 0;")

Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim da_line As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim ds As New DataSet()
da.Fill(ds, rs, "grp")

MsgBox("There are  total products." & ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString)
For Each a As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    lines = cn.Execute("select count(*) from tsklines where grp ='" & a(0) & "';")
    Dim ds_lines As New DataSet()
    da_line.Fill(ds_lines, lines, "lines")
    MsgBox("Lines for group." & a(0) & " -- " & ds_lines.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points -- you can work out the details.

1. You don't need the select statement inside the loop, because you can
   access the data in the row a.
2. You don't need to fill a dataset again, just update ds. You can
   update it all at once after the loop is done.